# Multiple time download change file name automatically in IE9

Tags: java, file, internet-explorer, download

I am trying to download [csv] file in java. But when I download again and again (20 times more)
download file name is changing like below.

```
 aaa.csv -> aaaCAPIIG73.csv  and 
         -> aaaCA44BTXJ.csv  and so on..
```

And here is some sample code:

```
response.setContentType("application/ms-excel");
String headValue = "attachment; " + "filename=aaa.csv";
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", headValue);
```

Please someone suggest me what should I do.
Thank you.

Comment: can you provide code samples?

Comment: @EvgenyLebedev I added some sample code in my question. Thanks for your comment.